# No GPIO controller on Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, iot, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I recently got myself a Raspberry Pi 3 model B, and wanted to get my feet wet with Windows 10 IoT by following some of the tutorials from Microsoft (in this case, [Blinky](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/kitblinky)).

I have however run into the issue that it always returns *"There is no GPIO controller on this device."*, and I have no idea why, I have more than triple checked all the wiring to make sure that is not the issue.

Does anyone know why `GpioController.GetDefault()` returns null?

Googling my issue has sadly not given me any solution, or even others with the same issue, so I imagine that it is likely some kind of error on my part but have no idea what.

Comment: General Purpose I/O https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=gpio%20controller you need to connect some sort of storage (or bios setting)

Comment: And methinks thou does not know Professor Google very well: https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=raspberry%20pi%20gpio%20error

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I've had no luck understanding any of those results, as from what I could ready, using windows 10 IoT on Raspberry Pi 3 should handle driver issues, and most other results from both of those google searches are for python projects, not C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seems to have been related to Windows 10 IoT itself, after letting it update via the device portal, the GPIO works as outlined in the tutorial.

Comment: What build of WinIoT Core were you running when you had the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, change the "Default Controller Driver" to Inbox Driver from your windows device portal.
to do this, go to "[windows 10 iot device ipaddress]:8080" in your browser. 
go to device tab. 
and select inbox driver.